# Position div and get external js file work onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript and CSS that works in fiddle but not when I use outside fiddle. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/74/)

1. when I plug it in to the html like below, it doesn't work. I believe I am missing some code?
2. the count `div` is not in the right position when I am not viewing it from jsfiddle. How can I position it relative to the search `input`?
3. it takes a minute  to generate the table, is it because my code is badly written?
   *well i do have 800rows*8columns

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="search-table.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search-table.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<table id="table-body">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>1-11</td>
            <td>1-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>2-11</td>
            <td>2-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3Asdqwe</td>
            <td>Cherry</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>3-11</td>
            <td>3-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4A</td>
            <td>Duriaen</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>4-11</td>
            <td>4-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>5-11</td>
            <td>5-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>6-11</td>
            <td>6-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3Asdqwe</td>
            <td>Cherry</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>7-11</td>
            <td>7-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4A</td>
            <td>Duriaen</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>8-11</td>
            <td>8-22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
//Perparing table
    /*
     *comment
     */
    $("<div>", {
        class: "tablewrapper"
    }).insertBefore("table#table-body");
    $("<table>", {
        class: "header"
    }).appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "headerwrapper"
    }).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
    $("table#table-body").appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "bodywrapper"
    }).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
    $("table#table-body>thead").clone().val("").appendTo("table.header");
    $("table.header>tr").removeClass("header_hidden");
    $("table#table-body").find("thead tr").addClass("header_hidden");
    $("table#table-body").find("tbody td:nth-child(2)").addClass("lefty");
    $("<input>", {
        type: "text"
    }).attr("id", "search-criteria").appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "s_box"
    }).insertAfter("div.headerwrapper"));
    $("<div>").attr("id", "count").insertAfter("div.s_box");


    resizeTable();
    var bodyTd = $("table#table-body tr td");

    $(window).resize(resizeTable);

    //search function
    $("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
        var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
            return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
        }).toLowerCase();
        var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

        if (keyword !== "") {
            $(row).each(function () {
                var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                //shorthand if function
                $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            });
            var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
            if (srowCount === 0) {
                if (!$(row).last().hasClass('s_empty')) {
                    $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Search not found</td></tr>');
                }
                $("tr.s_empty").show();
            } else {
                $("tr.s_empty").remove();
            }
        } else {
            $("tr.s_empty").remove();
            $(row).show();
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
        }

    });

    var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;

    function resizeTable() {
        //width adjustments
        $("table.header").width($("#table-body").width());
        $("div.s_box").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width() - 10)).height(($("table.header").height() - 9));
        $("input#search-criteria").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width() - 30)).height(($("div.s_box").height() - 0.05));
        var counter_h = ($("table.header").height() / 2 + $("table.header").height() - 1);
        $("div#count").css({
            "top": counter_h
        });

        var bodyTr = $("table#table-body tbody>tr:visible:eq(0) td");
        console.log(bodyTr);
        $("table.header tr:first th").each(function (index, value) {
            $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
        });

        //apply widths to every TD
        $("table#table-body tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            $(this).children().each(function (index) {
                $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make s_box relative so that count becomes absolute according to it

```
.s_box {
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: How can i know if it is relative to the input box or some other element?

Comment: by default it will be relative to your body tag... so if you specify any parent as relative all it child elements will be relative to it ... not the body

Comment: so...A) <body><div class="s_box"> relative to body, B) <body><table><div class="s_box"> relative to table?

Comment: Naman, I have tried using "relative". Now the div became a width object... and won't align to the right probably unless I give it a width. Please take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/75/ . I'm trying to make it look like this if possible, http://www.seanjmacisaac.com/projects/code/tablesort/#index-member-4

Answer (score 1):

There will error coming because of this JavaScript `$("<div>", {class: "tablewrapper"})` that used. It should be like this `$("<div>", {"class": "tablewrapper"})` for all places.

This is suggestion that,before preparing HTML from JavaScript use document ready event OR place your JavaScript at the end of html body elements.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="search-table.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//Perparing table
/*
*comment
*/




$(document).ready(function() {

    $("<div>", {"class": "tablewrapper"}).insertBefore("table#table-body");
$("<table>", {"class": "header"}).appendTo($("<div>", {"class": "headerwrapper"}).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
$("table#table-body").appendTo($("<div>", {"class": "bodywrapper"}).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
$("table#table-body>thead").clone().val("").appendTo("table.header");
$("table.header>tr").removeClass("header_hidden");
$("table#table-body").find("thead tr").addClass("header_hidden");
$("table#table-body").find("tbody td:nth-child(2)").addClass("lefty");
$("<input>", {type: "text"}).attr("id","search-criteria").appendTo($("<div>", {"class":"s_box"}).insertAfter("div.headerwrapper"));
$("<div>").attr("id","count").insertAfter("div.s_box");


resizeTable();
var bodyTd = $("table#table-body tr td");

$(window).resize(resizeTable);
    
    var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
    
    //search function
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
    return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
}).toLowerCase();
var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

if (keyword !== "") {
    $(row).each(function () {
        var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        //shorthand if function
        $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
    if (srowCount === 0) {
        if(!$(row).last().hasClass('s_empty'))
        {
            $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Search not found</td></tr>');
        }
        $("tr.s_empty").show();
    } else {
        $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    }
} else {
    $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    $(row).show();
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
}

});
});

function resizeTable() {
    //width adjustments
    $("table.header").width($("#table-body").width());
    $("div.s_box").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width()-10)).height(($("table.header").height()-9));
    $("input#search-criteria").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width()-30)).height(($("div.s_box").height()-0.05));
    var counter_h = ($("table.header").height()/2+$("table.header").height()-1);
    $("div#count").css({"top":counter_h});
    
    var bodyTr = $("table#table-body tbody>tr:visible:eq(0) td");
    console.log(bodyTr);
    $("table.header tr:first th").each(function (index, value) {
        $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
    });

    //apply widths to every TD
    $("table#table-body tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        $(this).children().each(function (index) {
            $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
        });
    });
}
</script>

<style>div.tablewrapper, div.headerwrapper, div.bodywrapper {
    border:0px;
}

div.headerwrapper {
    background-color:#1BA7F5;    
}

div.bodywrapper {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #1BA7F5;
}

table.header, table#table-body {
    border:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

table.header {
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5; 
    color:#FFF;
}

table.header th {
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table#table-body {
    width:100%;
}

table#table-body tr {
    line-height:30px;
    border-top:1px solid #C4C4C4;
}

table#table-body tr.header_hidden {
    display:none;
}

table#table-body tr:hover {
    background-color:#FFFF99;
}

table#table-body tbody td.lefty {
    text-align:left;
}

div.s_box {
padding: 5px 5px;
background: #c4c4c4;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

input#search-criteria {
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border: none;
border-radius: 6px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 23px;
background: #fff;
}

input#search-criteria:focus{
    outline:none;
}

div#count {
position: absolute;
right: 17px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #9EB4C2;
line-height: 19px;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 0 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
</body>
<table id="table-body">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>1-11</td>
            <td>1-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>2-11</td>
            <td>2-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3Asdqwe</td>
            <td>Cherry</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>3-11</td>
            <td>3-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4A</td>
            <td>Duriaen</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>4-11</td>
            <td>4-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>5-11</td>
            <td>5-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>6-11</td>
            <td>6-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3Asdqwe</td>
            <td>Cherry</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>7-11</td>
            <td>7-22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4A</td>
            <td>Duriaen</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>8-11</td>
            <td>8-22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for looking through all the code and suggestion. Do you mind to explain or show an example of the document.ready method?  Do i need to place the script in a function sth() {}?

Comment: so if i want to externally call the script (not from the html file), i will need to put $(document).ready(function() {...script...} save as some .js file. After that, add this to the html <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="search-table.js"></script>?